# Specify color of each point in 3d scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, matplotlib-3d

I have a 3D Plot that I created using matplotlib, and I have a list of rbg values that correspond to each point.

I have the X, Y, and Z data, and then I have a "color list" of the form:

```
[ (r,g,b), (r,g,b), ... , (r,g,b) ]
```

to match each (x, y, z) point.

Right now, I have

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

What's the appropriate way to incorporate those rgb tuples so that each point will be assigned a specific color?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used a `for` loop to individually assign each color to each point.  Here is my code:

```
X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [2, 5, 8]
Z = [6, 4, 5]
colors=["#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0066"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')


for i in range(len(X)):
    ax.scatter(X[i], Y[i], Z[i], color=colors[i])
plt.show()
```

The `for` loop goes point by point (hence the `[i]` in front of each X,Y,Z value) and gives a color one by one.  I used hex colors for my example, but you could probably use something else if you wanted.

Comment: This is extremely slow.

Answer (score 52):

If you don't want to use a for loop (which can be very slow for large lists) You can use the scatter command as is with an RGB color list, but you need to specify the colors as a vector of RGB (or RGBA) values between 0 and 1

```
X = [0, 1, 2]
Y = [0, 1, 2]
Z = [0, 1, 2]
C = np.array([[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c = C/255.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3 colored points]

Comment: can colors be specified as a hex string?

Comment: With the new matplotlib releases (at least with mpl version 3.2.1) you can directly pass color strings. I.e. `['b',green','red',...]` with length of points.

Comment: tnk u, saved my life

Answer (score 16):

Here is an example where the colors are calculated instead of specified by a literal list.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots

phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
x = np.sin(phi)
y = np.cos(phi)
rgb_cycle = (np.stack((np.cos(phi          ), # Three sinusoids,
                       np.cos(phi+2*np.pi/3), # 120° phase shifted,
                       np.cos(phi-2*np.pi/3)
                      )).T # Shape = (60,3)
             + 1)*0.5                         # scaled to [0,1].

fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(3,3))
ax.scatter(x,y, c=rgb_cycle, s=90)
fig.show()
```

[image: color ring]