# How to control the color of a specific column in a bar plot depending on it's xtick label?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a number of plots that show transcribed text from a speech to text engine in which I want to show the bars where the S2T engine transcribed correctly. I have labeled the subplots according to their expected values and now want to color the bars where the engine transcribed correctly in a different number than the other bars.

That means I need to access the color of the bars depending on their x-tick label. How do I do that?

Basically:

```
for xlabel in fig.xlabels:
   if(xlabel.text == fig.title):
      position = xlabel.position
      fig.colorbar(position, 'red')
```

Code that is used to generate the plots:

```py
def count_id(id_val, ax=None):
    title = df.loc[df['ID'] == id_val, 'EXPECTED_TEXT'].iloc[0]
    fig = df[df['ID']==id_val]['TRANSCRIPTION_STRING'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, figsize=(20,6), title=title)
    fig.set_xticklabels(fig.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha ='right')    
    fig.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4)
fig.suptitle('Classic subplot')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.4)

count_id('byte', axs[0,0])
count_id('clefting', axs[0,1])
count_id('left_hander', axs[0,2])
count_id('leftmost', axs[0,3])
count_id('right_hander', axs[1,0])
count_id('rightmost', axs[1,1])
count_id('wright', axs[1,2])
count_id('write', axs[1,3])
```

If anyone has an idea how to iterate over `axs` so I don't have to call `count_id()` 8 times, that'd be super helpful too. And yea I tried:

```py
misses = ['byte', 'cleftig', 'left_hander', 'leftmost', 'right_hander', 'rightmost', 'wright', 'write']

for ax, miss in zip(axs.flat, misses):
   count_id(ax, miss) # <- computer says no
```

[image]

Comment: When setting the color of the bars you can either pass just a color (all bars will be the same) or an array containing the color for each individual label. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578106/9142735

Comment: I mean, yea, but is there a way to access the color property after initializing plt.plot()?

Comment: Oh I'm not sure you can. Instead of using `DataFrame.plot` to create your figures you could use matplotlib's `plt.bar` directly and pass it your color array when creating each plot (like in the example above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the color of each bar according to the label both before and after plotting the bars.

I will use the sample data below for demonstration.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame({'word': list('abcdefg'), 'number': np.arange(1, 8)})
```

**1. Before plotting**:
This is the most common way of plotting a colored barplot. Your can pass *a list of colors* to `plt.plot()`.

```py
def plot_color_label_before(data, target):
    colors = ['red' if word == target else 'blue' for word in data.word]
    bars = plt.bar(x=data.word, height=data.number, color=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

The `data` passed to the function contains two columns, where the first lists all the words on your xtick, and the second lists the corrsponding numbers. The `target` is your expected word.
The code determines the colors for each word according to whether it is consistent with your target. For example,

```py
plot_color_label_before(data, 'c')
```

[image]

**2. After plotting**:
If you want to access the color after calling `plt.plot`, use `set_color` to change the color of a specific bar.

```py
def plot_color_label_after(data, target):
    bars = plt.bar(x=data.word, height=data.number, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
    for idx, word in enumerate(data.word):
        if word == target:
            bars[idx].set_color(c='yellow')
```

`plt.bar` returns a `BarContainer`, the i-th element of which is a patch (rectangle). Iterate over all the labels and change the color if the word hits the target.
For example,

```py
plot_color_label_after(data, 'c')
```

[image]

Finally, as to iterating over `axs`, just ravel it can solve the problem.

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4)
for ax in axs.ravel():
    ax.plot(...)
```